# Не могу сохранить данные пользователя в localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, json

Вот допустим у меня есть форма со входом и там нужно ввести имя. После этого нажать кнопку войти и у меня открывается другой сайт, т.е. кнопка "Войти" `<input type="submit" value="Войти">` и меня перебрасывает на другой html документ. Вот, я бы хотел чтобы я смог на другой странице получить те данные с первой страницы. Я думаю это через JSON делается, но как именно понять не могу. Просто я ввёл данные и если убрать переход на другую страницу и вывести в консоль значение, то оно выводится, а если добавить переход на другую страницу, то в консоль просто пустое значение передаётся. Я же надеюсь это через js делается?Выдаёт ошибку в консоли: test.js:228 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
at test.js:228:6

html

```
<form action="articles/article1.html" class="login-form" id="forma_vxoda">
                <h1>Регистрация</h1>
                <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Имя" id="includedContent Name_nick" required>
                <input type="text" name="pass" placeholder="Фамилия" required><br>
                <input type="email" name="login" placeholder="Электронная почта" required>
                <input type="text" name="pass" placeholder="Телефон" id="nomer" maxlength="12" required><br>
                <div class="forget-remember">
                    <input class="join" type="submit" value="Войти">
                    <a class="forget-pass midis_a" href="#"> Забыли пароль?</a>
                </div>
            </form>
```

js

```
var form = document.getElementById('forma_vxoda');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = new FormData(this);
    var result22 = 'Имя:'+data.get('login');
    console.log(result22);
});
```

Comment: да, через JS, при помощи GET и POST запросов

Comment: @Хацкер, я в вопросе добавил код. Через get делал и почему-то ошибку выдаёт